# How to do a constant loop animation using Sprites in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I have a sprite image and it's co-ordinate data in a txt file. I want to use it to do an animation that keeps playing constantly on loop (like a video on loop). How do I go about it? I'm new to LibGDX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

LibGdx comes with an animation class that makes animation with loops very easy. Check out this link:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation

If you're new to LibGdx you should take a look at it's Wiki page